# Border collapse not working in simple HTML table

Tags: css

Not sure why but border-collapse is not working in my simple HTML table even after I use `border-collapse: collapse`. Here's the JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y5ghL230/

Can somebody help, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`border-collapse` has to be defined for `table`, see my fiddle:

```
table {border-collapse: collapse}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y5ghL230/1/

Comment: Well! . . . :-) Will accept your answer once it allows me to.